# Doctrine Query how many times an Entity appears on other table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Suppose I have two tables:

```
Customer
id | name
1  | John
2  | Chris

Sales
id | client_id | price
1  | 1         | 100
2  | 1         | 200
3  | 1         | 300
4  | 2         | 150
5  | 2         | 250
```

The relationship between the tables is 1:M

What my query should look like if I want to return the data below?

```
client_name | number of sales
John        | 3
Chris       | 2
```

Right now my querybuilder looks like this, just a simple select *

```
$objs = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                    ->getRepository(Customer::class)
                    ->createQueryBuilder('obj');

            $objs = $objs->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Should I use some sort of join, or subquery? I would appreciate a little guidance, thank you.

Comment: Can you try something first, so we can help you from that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what @Arno Hilke wrote, but with some changes (and assuming your `Customer` entity is actually named `Client`):

```php
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
    ->getRepository(Client::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c.name as client_name, COUNT(s.client) as number_of_sales')
    ->join('c.sales', 's')
    ->groupBy('s.client')
    ->getQuery();

$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Join your sales table. Group by customers and count the occurrences of each customer. Something like this should work, depending on your exact entity definitions:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
           ->getRepository(Customer::class)
           ->createQueryBuilder('customer')
           ->select('customer.id as id, count(customer.id) as number');
           ->join('customer.sales', 'sales')
           ->groupBy('sales');


$result = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Arno Hilke and @Michał Tomczuk.

I changed the code a little to fit my needs. I needed some conditions in the select, so instead of COUNT I used SUM, the code ended like this:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
              ->getRepository(Customer::class)
              ->createQueryBuilder('c')
              ->select("c.name, SUM(CASE WHEN s.conditioneOne = 'valueOne' AND s.conditionTwo = 'valueTwo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_sales")
                    ->join('c.sales', 's')
                    ->groupBy('s.costumer')
                    ->orderBy('number_of_sales', 'DESC');

$results = $query->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```